# Why can I not use my Propel ORM classes inside of other classes or functions?

Tags: php, orm, propel

This code works :

```
  1 <?
  2 
  5 require( '/var/www/Propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php' );
  6 // Initialize Propel with the runtime configuration
  7 Propel::init("/home/foo/Projects/bar/classes/orm/build/conf/myconfig-conf.php");
  8 // Add the generated 'classes' directory to the include path
  9 set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/classes/orm/build/classes/" . get_include_path());
 10 
 11 $PQ = new ProjectsQuery();
 12 $projects = ProjectsQuery::create()->find();
 13 print_r( $projects );
 15 
 16 ?>
```

However, if I put this exact same code inside of a class or a function (I will use a function for this example) , I get an error, and the objects are not `print_r`

```
  1 <?
  2 
  3 require( '/var/www/Propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php' );
  4 // Initialize Propel with the runtime configuration
  5 Propel::init("/home/foo/Projects/bar/classes/orm/build/conf/myconfig-conf.php");
  6 // Add the generated 'classes' directory to the include path
  7 set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/classes/orm/build/classes/" . get_include_path());
  8 
  9     public function foo()
 10     {   
 11         $PQ = new ProjectsQuery();
 12         $projects = ProjectsQuery::create()->find();
 13         print_r( $projects );
 14     }   
 15 ?>
```

The error that I am getting in the log file says

> [Wed Feb 08 03:03:02 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM' at line 1' in /var/www/Propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php:1284\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/Propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php    (1284): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 /var/www/Propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php(1137): ModelCriteria->doSelect(Object(PropelPDO))\n#2 /home/foo/Projects/bar/models/Projects.php(12): ModelCriteria->find()\n#3  /home/foo/Projects/bar/controllers/Projects.php(11): foo()\n#4 /home/foo/Project    s/bar/project-listings.php(6): Projects->__construct()\n#5 {main}\n\nNext exception 'PropelException' with message 'Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT  FROM ] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to yo in /var/www/Propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php on line 1287

Can anyone with more Propel ORM experience tell me how I can use propel in a class or a function.  Only being able to use it in the first way that I mentioned is not going to work.  And I am just using straight php.  No framework or anything else.

Comment: Is it just me or there's a syntax error in that error message?

Answer (score 0):

What you aren't including here is the actual calling of the `foo()` function, which may be hiding the real issue. If you call it from a different directory than the file containing `foo()` is in, then `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` could be different, thus changing your `include_path` to not actually point to the Propel classes.

Try printing out `get_include_path()` after you set it on line 7 and see what you have, make sure the the full path to the Propel files is correct.